# advantages and disadvantages of DynDNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, dyndns

1. what are the advantages of DynDNS?
2. what are the dis-advantages of DynDNS?
3. DynDNS Vs HttpVPN Proxy

thank you very much

Comment: Are you asking about the [company](http://www.dyndns.com/) and its products or the general concept of Dynamic updating of DNS?

Comment: just for general conceptual understanding

Answer (score 1):

It is next to impossible to contrast pros and cons without any reasonable reference to your configuration and what you are trying to accomplish.

DynDNS typically has nothing to do with VPN or proxy technologies unless you are referring to some specific functionality that they are offering.